# wordpress query (shortcode) returns always the first post

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have made a shortcode inside my plugin, which is working great .
The shortcode needs to take some parameters and create a custom loop with output.

One of the parameters is how many posts to output the loop for ($markers)

```
$args=array(
                'meta_key'=>'_mykey',
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                'post_type'=>'post',
                'orderby'=>'date',
                'order'=>'DESC',
                'posts_per_page'=>$markers,

);

  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
           $wp_query->query($args);

if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while (($wp_query->have_posts()) ) : $wp_query->the_post();

// do the loop using get_the_id() and $post->id

endwhile;endif;
wp_reset_query();//END query
```

On occations I will need to have data from ALL posts `($markers = '-1' )` and sometimes only one `($markers = '1' )` or muliple `($markers = 'x')`.

All of those work great on single pages / posts - but My problem is that when this function is in a place where I have more than one post (!is_single) and (`$ markers = '1'` )it will always return the data for the LATEST post , and not for the correct one ..
(for example in the default wordpress theme, where it would display10 posts - they will all be the same data )

It is obviously a problem of the `$post->ID` - but how can I have the correct post ID when doing a custom loop OUTSIDE the wp loop ?

I tried to ovverride the problem by

```
global $post;
 $thePostIDtmp = $post->ID; //get the ID before starting new query as temp id
 $wp_query = new WP_Query();
 $wp_query->query($args);
// Start Custom Loop

if (!is_single()){
$post_id_t = $thePostIDtmp;}
else {
$post_id_t = $post->ID;}
```

and then use  `$post_id_t` - but it did not seems to work ,
Should I not use get_the_id() ? or should I not use query (and use get_posts) ??

Any ideas / solutions / thoughts ??

Answer (score 1):

I would use query_posts(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)rather than override the $wp object. You should be able to include as many loops on the page as you want with this.  If you have problems with this you can use: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query just before you call it.

I find this: http://blog.cloudfour.com/wordpress-taking-the-hack-out-of-multiple-custom-loops/
takes a bit of the pain away too.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I suspected that I will need to use query_posts() or get_posts() it does not seems to help in my case , I am not sure quite why ..

Comment: have you tried echoing out the post id so you can see when it changes. If you echo it out within the if statement and when you set the tmp variable it might help you see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two sorts of querying posts in WordPress: Those that alter the main loop and those that do not. If you want to change the main loop like the one used to display category archive pages then use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). It let's you do exactly that. Delete, change and append parameters of the default query to change the outcome of a typical page.
query_posts has some [drawbacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats) though.

Then there are queries that are just used to get stuff out of the database to play around with e.g. displaying the latest post titles in the sidebar or the attachments of the current post.

To do that create a new WP_Query object that will build your custom loop independently of the main loop like so:

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Then there is [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) which is like the little brother of WP_Query. It has an easier interface in my opinion and returns an array with the results that is easier to work with.
It looks like this:

```
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
     echo "<li>";
     the_title();
     echo "</li>";
endforeach;
```

Inside the foreach template tags like get_the_id() will work.

Comment: Thanks . I will look at your proposed methods . my problem is not that the query is not working - my problem is that it returns the FIRST post over and over again . basically - inside the "normal" wp loop, in the content - I execute my shortcode , but if i set the 'posts_per_page'=> 1 - it will always return the first (same) post. get_the_id() works, as well as $post->ID - but they always return the values for the same post ...  otherwise, in other pages there is no problem (because the wordpress loop is always only 1 ..) .

Comment: "my problem is not that the query is not working - my problem is that it returns the FIRST post over and over again" well to me THAT sounds like your query is not working ;)
Just stay away from the main query. Create a new WP_Query object or use get_posts() and you will have no problems.

Comment: well, unfortunatly I need to get AFK now, but I will try as soon as I can . My query works fine on all occations, except the one described . I will try to explain, I have 2 example posts, one has $markers = -1 and the other markers = 1 . if I use the get_posts - the first one gives me the exact same data (for post_meta) and the second one works great , if I change to new post object - the first one works fine, and the second one gives the first marker of the first post as meta data .. I know it is a bit confusing, I will try to post an example as soon as I get back .